# How do you copy rows if a cell is empty?

Tags: vba, excel, automation, copy

We are using an Excel file to keep track of the drug therapy.

Once a Drug Therapy ends, I'll write "yes" in column K (probably change that to a date later on). I've prepared a sheet for every Month (named: 01 - 12) and I want it to automatically copy rows which have no entry in column K into the next spread sheet . The range is `3A:K22`. (Rows 1 & 2 have Data that shouldn't be modified. I hope I have described it in enough detail for you to understand. If not I'd gladly clarify any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly you want to copy each row where the cell in Column K is empty?

```
Dim rCell As Range, rng As Range, NextRow As Long
Set rng = Workbook.Sheets("SheetName").Range("K3:K22")

'loop through each K cell
For Each rCell In rng
    If IsEmpty(rCell) Then
        'copy that row
        Range("A" & rCell.Row & "K" & rCell.Row).Copy
        'if desired here can be code to check the date to see which sheet to insert into
        NextRow = Workbook.Sheets("MonthSheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        Workbook.Sheets("MonthSheet").Range("A" & NextRow & "K" & NextRow).Paste
    End If
Next rCell
```

This will check each cell in the K column to see if it is empty, if it is it will copy it to the next blank row in the Month Sheet

Comment: Thank you Evan. This Looks really promising. Ive been trying to implement this Code but when using it, i get a runtime error, and dont know how to correct it. the debugger stops at this line: Range("A" & rCell.Row & "K" & rCell.Row).Copy. Can someone explain to me how to use it?

Comment: try adding `sheet.select` and `range.select` to the code, sheet ouside of the loop and range inside the loop before the copy method.

The copy method might be failing becasue a different sheet is active.